# Brackets for methods in tooltips in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When I select a method in VS hints, it puts ONLY the method names, **WITHOUT BRACKETS**. Earlier I wrote code in Jetbrains Rider 2020.1 and it inserted methods with brackets.

Current tooltip:
[image: Tip]

Choose method, but it inserted without brackets:
[image: Choose method, but it inserted without brackets]

I want this:
[image: I want this]

Comment: What brackets are you talking about? Parentheses after auto-completing a method name?

Comment: Can you describe what you are talking about a little better?  What's _VS hints_ (I'm assuming it's some Visual Studio feature - how do you access it)?  What are method names with brackets

Comment: I added pictures to the question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Autocomplete Method Brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21466150/autocomplete-method-brackets)

Comment: No, I don't need auto-closing of brackets, i need automatic inserting brackets after methods. Or I need to install ReSharper?

Comment: Ok. I install ReSharper plugin for VS 2019. This solved my problem for the next 30 days))